# Error while running code in the TMS320C6713 DSK?

Tags: c, signal-processing, fft, processor

I am trying to run the following code to implement FFT in the DSP processor whose model is mentioned above. The code is written in C Langauge

```
//All codes submitted by  Srivatsa Sinha
/*Include Library Files*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

/*Templates*/
//#define ll long long
#define cmp struct complex
#define print_cmp(z) printf("%lf + %lfj\n",z.re,z.im)
#define M_PI 3.14159265358979

struct complex
{
    float re;
    float im;
}res,w,w_var,t,u;

cmp signal[4];
cmp result[4];
int j,s,k,n,z,x,no_of_bit,rev,pow2[10],m,a;
void calc()
{
    pow2[0]=1;
    for(k=1; k<10; k++) { pow2[k] = pow2[k-1]*2;}
}

cmp add(cmp a, cmp b)
{
    res.re = a.re + b.re;
    res.im = a.im + b.im;
    return res;
}

cmp sub(cmp a, cmp b)
{
    res.re = a.re - b.re;
    res.im = a.im - b.im;
    return res;
}

cmp mul(cmp a, cmp b)
{
    res.re = a.re*b.re - a.im*b.im;
    res.im = a.re*b.im + a.im*b.re;
    return res;
}

cmp cmp_pow(cmp base, int exp)
{
    res.re = 1.0; res.im = 0.0;
    for(a=1; a<=exp; a++)
        res = mul(res,base);
    return res;
}

void bit_rev()
{
    no_of_bit = log2(n);
    for(z=0; z<n; z++)
    {
      rev = 0;
      for(x=0; x<no_of_bit; x++)
      {
        if((z>>x)&1)
        {
          rev = rev|(1<<(no_of_bit-1-x));
        }
      }
      result[rev] = signal[z];
    }
}

void fft()
{
  bit_rev();
  for(s=1; s<=(int)log2(n); s++)
  {
     m = pow2[s];
     w.re = (float)cos(((float)2.0*(float)M_PI)/(float)m); w.im = (float)-1.0*sin(((float)2.0*(float)M_PI)/(float)m);
     for(k=0; k<n; k+=m)
     {
       w_var.re = 1; w_var.im = 0;
       for(j=0; j<=(m/2 - 1); j++)
       {
         t = mul(w_var, result[k+j+(int)(m/2)]);
         u = result[k+j];
         result[k+j] = add(u,t);
         result[k+j+(int)(m/2)] = sub(u,t);
         w_var = mul(w_var, w);
       }
     }

  }
}

void dft()
{
    w.re = (float)cos(((float)2.0*(float)M_PI)/(float)n); w.im = (float)-1.0*sin(((float)2.0*(float)M_PI)/(float)n);
    for(k=0; k<n; k++)
    {
        result[k].re = 0.0; result[k].im = 0.0;
        for(j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            result[k] = add(result[k],mul(signal[j],cmp_pow(w,k*j)));
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
   calc();
   printf("Enter length of the signal: ");
   scanf("%d",&n);
   printf("Enter the signal sequence: \n");
   for(k=0;k<n; k++)
   {
       scanf("%f",&signal[k].re);
       scanf("%f",&signal[k].im);
   }
   fft();
   printf("The Result of FFT is: \n");
   for(k=0; k<n; k++)
   {
     print_cmp(result[k]);
   }
   dft();
   printf("The Result of DFT is: \n");
   for(k=0; k<n; k++)
   {
     print_cmp(result[k]);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

The following files are added before compilation:

```
hello.cmd The Linker file
rts6700.lib The Library file
```

Although the code compiles successfully, but when built gives following error:

```
can't allocate .stack size 00000400 (page 0) in IRAM (avail: 000003ec)
can't allocate .sysmem size 00000400 (page 0) in IRAM (avail: 000003ec)
can't allocate .cio size 00000120 (page 0) in IRAM (avail: 0000010a)
errors in input - ./Debug/FFTa.out not built
```

Please help??

Comment: Before including this rts6700.lib, did a simple 'hello.cmd' has been built for your target DSP ?

Comment: You are running out of IRAM. Either change your memory configuration to increase IRAM, or move those sections to other portions like SDRAM or others.

Comment: Can you please explain me the terms IRAM and SDRAM, and how do we transfer portions to SDRAM?. I am an undergrad and pretty new to DSP Processors, and thus is unaware. Its the code i am writing as a part of my day to day experimenting with technologies in college labs

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the memories.  It has been a couple years since I worked with the TI tools.   I no longer have access to their documentation, but it looks like you need to set your linker control file.  If you are using CodeComposer, you will need to create a target (or designate a simulation model) which will be defining where your RAM locations are.  If you have a need to get high performance out of the processor, you will want to dig into the various memory types in order to minimize bus latencies.